# C# resize indexed colour bitmap and maintain colours

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gdi+

I have a `Bitmap` which is in 256-colour indexed format, I need to resize it so I create a new `Bitmap` in 24-bit RGB format and draw it using a `Graphics` object as I cannot create a graphics object from an indexed colour bitmap. I then need to save the resized image back as an indexed colour format so I use `FormatConvertedBitmap` to convert to indexed colour like this:

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
FormatConvertedBitmap converted = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
converted.BeginInit();
converted.Source = bitmapSource;
converted.DestinationFormat = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed8;
converted.DestinationPalette = new BitmapPalette(bitmapSource, 256);
converted.EndInit();
```

This works but the solid colours are now grainy and contain other colour pixels. Is there a better method to either resize an indexed colour image or to maintain the solid colours?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is pretty inevitable.  The core property you want to control to influence this is Graphics.InterpolationMode.  A high quality selection like Bicubic will add a lot of colors to the resized image.  Trying to whack it back to 256 colors is going to produce a grainy image.  You could use NearestNeighbor instead to reduce the number of added colors but you'll end up with a blocky image.

You could try the GIF encoder, it is forced to resample the image back to 256 colors as well.  It uses a dithering algorithm.  But tends to produce flecky artifacts that become noticeable when the image has large areas of similar colors, like a blue sky.  There is no magical cure beyond simply not resampling back.  There is just no point in doing that with the wonderful hardware we have these days.